# appending text in textview not switching keyboard from uppercase to lowercase in ios

Tags: ios, swift

if I append some text in text view by tapping button its not switching keyboard from uppercase to lowercase. but its switching from uppercase to lowercase if I write from the keyboard. and I set

```
textView.autocapitalizationType = .sentences
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer.previously I used textview.inserttext() method for insert text now if I use text view.text.append() then it switching keyboard from uppercase to lowercase.